# NodeJS - Dependency Injection Confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am attempting to create an API endpoint in an Express/Node project I am working on. The issue is returning a router for the API routes. Also, I do not fully understand what is happening.

Everything for the app is setup in server.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const env = process.env;

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const routes = require('./routes/routes');
const ActiveDirectory = require('./ActiveDirectory');
const HeyListen = require('./HeyListen')(io, ActiveDirectory);
const HeyListenHandler = require('./HeyListenHandler')(HeyListen);

const sesh = {
    secret: env.JWT_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
};

process.title = 'Hey Listen Server';

// Server Start
server.listen(env.APP_PORT, () => console.log('Listening on Port: ' + env.APP_PORT));

// Setup
app.use(express.static('lib/creator/public'));
app.use(express.json());
if ( env.ENVIRONMENT === 'production' ) {
    app.set('trust proxy', 1);
    sesh.cookie.secure = true;
}
app.use(session(sesh));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views','./lib/creator/views');

// Routing
app.use('/api', routes.api);
app.use('/', routes.creator);
```

routes.js

```
const api = require('./api');
const creator = require('./creator');

module.exports = {  api: api, creator: creator };
```

api.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const APIController = require('../Controllers/APIController');

module.exports = (HeyListen) => {
    const controller = new APIController(HeyListen);
    router.use(/\/(create|update)/, controller.middleware);
    router.post('/token', controller.token);
    router.post('/create', controller.create.bind(controller));
    router.post('/update', controller.update.bind(controller));
    return router;
}
```

The main issue is `module.exports = (HeyListen) => { .. }`. `HeyListen` isn't a reference to the `HeyListen` variable at the top of server.js and `app.use('/api', routes.api)` doesn't get an instance of `Router` from Express but a general function. This leads to any requests made to `/api/x` time out.

`console.log(routes.creator)` returns `{ [Function: router] .. }` whereas `routes.api` returns `[Function]`.

What I want is to pass `HeyListen` from server.js to `api.js` so it can be used in the APIController. `HeyListen` handles basically all the requests and has helper functions that I want to use in APIController -- I do not want to recreate it in the controller itself.

### Update

I managed to pass everything as it should be and is now working. However, I am unsure if this is the "right way" to do it.

server.js

```
// Everything else is the same
app.use('/api', routes.api(HeyListen));
```

routes.js

```
// Everything else is the same
module.exports = {  api(HeyListen) { return api(HeyListen) }, creator: creator };
```

And api.js is exactly the same as above.

Comment: Don't see why you have to change `routes.js` at all here, the problem was you just weren't calling the `api` function.

Comment: More a simplification note than anything functional, but `module.exports = { api, creator }` should accomplish the same thing as the version you have in your `Update`. (That's using es6 shorthand property names, and also simplifying `api`: assigning the local function definition instead of defining a function property to invoke and return the local function. same thing, just shorter)

Comment: @James thanks for the comment. That fixed it and I feel pretty silly for not catching that in the first place. If you want to make an answer I'll mark it correct.

Comment: @David784 thanks for the suggestion. Always looking to improve the code when/where I can.